# Connect server database in Android (emulator)

Tags: php, android, mysql, apache

I try to connect server database with my Android app (php + mysql).

When I do makeHttpRequest Logcat shows something like "httphostconnectexception connection to http //localhost refused"

I know you have been asked several times and I tried to fix it but seeing each response is still not working.

**IMPORTANT: 
1. "" works in my browser but not in my emulator. 
Two.'ve Tried http://jsonlint.com json object and correct.**

Thank you for your attention!

```
protected String doInBackground(String... args) 
{
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();


        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest("http://10.0.2.2/test/get_all_users.php", "GET", params);

        //......
}
```

Comment: in such a case you should take a look on the server logs

Comment: Which url did you use in your browser? Your browser is the one of your pc of the one from the emulator?

Comment: I have permission. In my browser it works with localhost/test... At emulator's browser it works with the same  url of the code: 10.0.2.2/test...

Answer (score 0):

Have you check Internet Permission. if it is ok then put here your menifest file.

Answer (score 0):

I really do not know which was the problem, but it works. I have returned to restart Xampp and all its components, the two emulators use and even the Mac and it works (I think it had something to do with Apache but I have no idea).

Thanks for your answers